# Divergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_n}{S_n}$ where $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$, when $S_n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence such that $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ diverges.
>   I'm trying to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a_n}{S_n}$ diverges.

I tried summation by parts, limit comparison and Stolz theorem in many different combinations and am still stuck with nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that, for every $M\geqslant N$,
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^M\frac{a_n}{S_n}\geqslant\sum_{n=N+1}^M\frac{a_n}{S_M}=1-\frac{S_N}{S_M}$$
hence, for every $N$, considering that $S_M\to+\infty$ when $M\to\infty$,
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{S_n}\geqslant1.
$$
This shows that the series diverges since *the rest of a summable series converges to zero*.

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: Instead of "rest" I would say "remainder."

Answer (score 4):

HINT : If $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{S_n}=0$
$$
\frac{a_n}{S_n}\sim -\ln(1-\frac{a_n}{S_n})=\ln(\frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}})
$$

Details :

$$\sum_{p=1}^{n}\ln(\frac{S_p}{S_{p-1}})=\sum_{p=1}^n \ln(S_p)-\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\ln(S_p)=\ln(S_n)-\ln{S_0}$$

As the series $\sum a_n$ diverges then the series $\sum\ln(\frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}})$ diverges and therefore $\sum \frac{a_n}{S_n}$

Comment: Nice approach (although the $\sim$ step needs to be made more rigorous).

Comment: @Did You are right. But initially it was only a 'trick' to help user136640 which I hope he can do it by itself.

Comment: I don't think you can make this approach work, because there is no reason to expect $\frac{a_n}{S_n}$ to be close to $0$. It could very well tend to $1$ for instance, in which case $-\ln\left(1-\left(\frac{a_n}{S_n}\right)\right)$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat We are dealing with two cases: first one  -we do not have $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{S_n}=0$ and the second case where the limit is $0$.

Comment: Missed that, my bad!${}{}{}$