# If $\sum_{n_0}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges prove that $\sum_{n_0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n} = +\infty $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I've tried to use the limit test:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = C$
in the series of $a_n$ and $\frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}$ but it was inconclusive.

The question does not especify the sign of $a_n$ but proving it for positives would already help.

I think the sign can change as long as the partial sums never get to be zero. Like if the series has only negative numbers the result seems to stil hold.

[Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{S_n}$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130905/show-that-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-fraca-ns-n-diverges?rq=1)

Comment: Are we to assume all terms are positive?

Comment: Random thought, but the terms remind me of the identity: $$1=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{(a_0+1)(a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_3+1)(a_4+1)...(a_k+1)}+\frac{1}{(a_0+1)(a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_3+1)(a_4+1)...(a_n+1)}$$
For all $\{a_i \}$ and integers $n\ge 0$ , so long as $a_j\ne 0$ for any integer $0\leq j \leq n$

Comment: Are you sure ?  I've tried the stolz theorem and thus I calculated $a_{n+1} -a_n$ of the series and it didn't look telescopic

Comment: @onlyme I was thinking of something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the $a_n$ are non-negative. To prove that the series diverges to $+\infty$, it is enough to prove that for every $N\in\Bbb N$, there exists $N'>N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=N}^{N'}\frac{a_n}{a_0+\cdots+a_n}\geq \frac12$$
So fix $N>0$, and notice that for every $M>N$
$$\sum_{n=N}^{M}\frac{a_n}{a_0+\cdots+a_n}\geq\sum_{n=N}^{M}\frac{a_n}{a_0+\cdots+a_{M}}=\frac{a_N+\cdots+a_{M}}{a_0+\cdots+a_{M}}=1-\frac{C}{a_0+\cdots+a_{M}}$$
where $C=a_0+\cdots+a_{N-1}$ is a constant. The second term is of the form "constant over something that tends to infinity" and so tends to $0$, and eventually we get a minoration by $\frac12$, showing that the series diverges to infinity.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you showed that the series diverges or if it can have a limit greater than 1. Thank you for the answer

Comment: It diverges to $+\infty$, because say we have started with $N_0=0$, we find $N_1>N_0$ such that the sum of terms from $N_0$ to $N_1-1$ is greater than $\frac12$, and we then find $N_2$ such that the sum of terms from $N_1$ to $N_2-1$ is greater than $\frac12$, etc... After $k$ iterations the sum will of terms from $0=N_0$ to $N_k-1$ will be greater than $\frac{k}2$.

Answer (score 15):

This problem has an interesting history from the early days of real analysis attached to it. I really like this story and the proof it contains of the problem in this question is also different from the other answers posted.

---

In 1827 a *M. Oliver* published a proof in Crelle's Journal (*Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik*) of the following theorem:

> Theorem *M. Oliver*: A series of positive terms converges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = 0$.

Not long after this paper had been published Niels Henrik Abel responded with a short note noting that the theorem "*does not seem to hold true*" as the series  $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ diverges but $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \frac{1}{n\log(n)} = 0$ contradicting the theorem above.

Abel then followed it up by another short note showing that there cannot exist *any* function $\phi(n)$ such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n ~~~\text{converges} \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(n)a_n = 0$$

The proof is remarkably simple and uses the lemma below (which coincides with the problem this question asks for). I will here present Abel's original proof.  It's from memory so it's not word for word but the main idea behind the proof should be intact.

---

> Lemma: if a series of positive terms $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges then so does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{a_1+a_2+\ldots + a_{k-1}}$.

Proof: Let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$, then

$$\log\left(\frac{s_k}{s_{k-1}}\right) =  \log\left(1+\frac{a_k}{s_{k-1}}\right) < \frac{a_k}{s_{k-1}}$$

since $\log(1+x) < x$. Summing over $k=2,3,\ldots,n$ the left hand side telescopes to give

$$\log\left(\frac{s_n}{s_{1}}\right) < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s_{k-1}}$$

Now if $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ diverges then so does the logarithm of $s_n$ and it follows that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s_{k-1}}$ also diverges.

---

Proof of Abel's theorem above: Assume there exist a function $\phi(n)$ with the properties that $\sum a_k$ converges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(n)a_n = 0$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\phi(k)}$ diverges since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(n)\frac{1}{\phi(n)} = 1$. By the lemma above this implies that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{\phi(k)}}{\frac{1}{\phi(1)}+\frac{1}{\phi(2)} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\phi(k-1)}}$$
also diverges but
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(n)\frac{\frac{1}{\phi(n)}}{\frac{1}{\phi(1)}+\ldots + \frac{1}{\phi(n-1)}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\phi(1)}+\ldots + \frac{1}{\phi(n-1)}} = 0$$

which would indicate that it is convergent. No such function $\phi(n)$ can therefore exist.

Answer (score 7):

Intuition comes from the continuous analogue: if $f : [a, \infty) \to \Bbb{R}^+$ is a positive piecewise continuous function such that $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = \infty$, then

$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)} \, dx = \log F(\infty) - \log F(a) = \infty $$

where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ (which is also positie on $[a, \infty)$. Bringing this idea to discrete setting is not hard. Indeed, when $a_k$'s are positive then you may apply Stolz theorem to

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_k / s_k)}{\log s_n}. \tag{1} $$

More precisely, we have either $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n / s_n > 0$ or that (1) converges to 1, and in either case the series diverges.

Comment: I like your answer a lot, if I can prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{s_n} = 0 $ or at least that it exists it's done. I've tried using the limit test again but this was useless.

Comment: @onlyme, If $a_{n}/s_{n} \nrightarrow 0$ then the series just diverges. So you may assume $a_{n}/s_{n} \to 0$ and show that the series still diverges by examining (1). (Actually both cases can arise.)

Comment: true, thanks a lot man.

Comment: Anyone have anything for the case where  not all the $a_n$ are non-negative?

Comment: @user254665 If $\sum_na_n\to\infty$, then the $a_n$ are eventually nonnegative and you can use essentially the same argument as this or Oliver's answer. If $\sum_na_n\to-\infty$ by symmetry the same proof shows that $\sum_na_n/s_n\to-\infty$, so the theorem as stated is false. If $\sum_na_n$ doesn't converge to anything, the theorem is false: for example if $(a_n)=1,-3,6,-3,-3,6,-3,\dots$ (period 3 with one initial term) then $(s_n)=1,-2,4,1,-2,4,\dots$ and $(a_n/s_n)=1,3/2,3/2,-3,3/2,3/2,-3,\dots$, so $\sum_na_n/s_n$ cycles through $1,5/2,4$ without converging.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro. Let  $a_n=1/n$ when $n$ is odd and $a_n=-2^{-n}$ when n is even. Then $\sum _n a_n=\infty$ but $a_n<0$ for infinitely many $n.$

Comment: I wonder that M. Oliver's "theorem" got published as it's so easy to produce counter-examples. Besides Abel's example, consider $a_n=2^{-n}$ when $n$ is not a power of $ 2, $ and $a_n= 1/n$ when $n$ is a power of  $2. $

Comment: @user254665 Yeah, it took me too long to give a proof/counterexample for this case. I meant to say that $s_n$ is eventually nonnegative, but $a_n$ may not be. Abel's proof in Winther's answer works even if the $a_n$ are not positive, provided that $s_n>0$ for all $n$, because $\log(1+x)\le x$ holds also for $-1<x<0$.