# If $u_n>0$ and $\sum u_n$ diverges and $s_n=u_1+u_2+\dots+u_n$ then " $s_{n+p}>2s_n$" is justified or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $u_n>0$ and $\sum u_n$ diverges and $s_n=u_1+u_2+\dots+u_n$ then is the claim that "we can choose $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_{n+p}>2s_n$" is justified?

I know the following

1. $\sum u_n$ diverges iff sequence of partial sum $\{s_n\}$ diverges
2. sequence $\{s_n\}$ is monotone increasing

But how to show that  $s_{n+p}>2s_n$ is justified?

In the link [Is my proof ok? If $\sum u_n$ diverges then $\sum \frac {u_n} {u_1 + u_2 + \dots + u_n}$ also diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865038/is-my-proof-ok-if-sum-u-n-diverges-then-sum-frac-u-n-u-1-u-2-dots?rq=1)

[image]

Only want to get the result $s_{n+p}>2s_n$. Please help

Comment: Since your method does not work I have provided a different argument to show that $\sum \frac {u_n} {s_n}$ is divergent. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If $u_n = 1$, this sequence verifies your hypotheses. However, $s_n = n$, so

$$
s_{n+p} > 2s_n \iff n+p > 2n \iff p >n
$$

which of course for a fixed $p$ it cannot hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $s_{n+p} > 2s_n$ is not true

Comment: @user1942348 For this example, it will be false every time that $ n > p $.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u_n >0$ for all $n$ and $\sum u_n =\infty$.  If $\sum \frac {u_k} {s_k}$ is convergent then $\sum_{k=n}^{m}\frac {u_k} {s_k} \to 0$ as $n,m\to \infty$. We prove that this is not the case. We need the following inequality: $1-x_1 x_2...x_j \leq \sum_{i=1}^{j} (1-x_i)$ if each $x_i \in [0,1]$. This inequality can be proved by induction. From this we get $\sum_n^{m}\frac {u_k} {s_k}=\sum_n^{m}\frac {s_k-s_{k-1}} {s_k} \geq 1-\prod_{k=n}^{m}\frac {s_{k-1}} {s_k} =1-\frac {s_{n-1}} {s_m} \to 1$ as $m \to \infty$. This completes the proof.

Comment: I request you for the proof of $s_{n+p}>2s_n$