# show that $\frac {a_{N+1}}{s_{N+1}} +...+\frac {a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}\geq 1 -\frac {a_{N}}{s_{N+k}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, divergent-series

Suggestion of how to do it, please.

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a succession in $\mathbb R  ^+$ such that  $\sum a_n$ diverges, and if  $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_k}$.
>   show that $\frac {a_{N+1}}{s_{N+1}} +...+\frac {a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}\geq 1 -\frac {s_{N}}{s_{N+k}} $

and infer that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{s_n}}$ diverge.

Please.thank

Comment: The right-hand side of the inequality is different in the title and the question body.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388898/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1865038/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac {a_{N+1}}{s_{N+1}} +...+\frac {a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}\geq\frac {a_{N+1}}{s_{N+k}} +...+\frac {a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}=$$
$$=\frac{s_{N+k}-s_N}{s_{N+k}}= 1 -\frac {s_{N}}{s_{N+k}} $$

Comment: is $\frac {a_{N+1}}{s_{N+1}} +...+\frac {a_{N+k}}{s_{N+k}}\geq 1 -\frac {s_{N}}{s_{N+k}} $

Comment: @VERA Yes, of course. See my solution.