# Test whether or not $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n\left(1 +\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

I am trying to use limit comparison test to test this series,

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n\left(1 +\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$

$\lim_\limits{{n\to \infty }}\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)$

$=\lim _\limits{{n\to \infty }}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

$=\lim _\limits{{n\to \infty }}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$

This limit will always larger than $0$, therefore

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n\left(1 +\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ diverges.

Is this working valid or there is a better solution for this question?

Comment: What do you mean when you write "This limit will always larger than $0$"? The limit *is* $0$.

Comment: I would compare it with $\sum\bigl(1/(n\log n)\bigr)$.

Comment: For the reason why $\frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}}{\ln n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$: adapt the proof of the integral test to get a pair of bounds on the sum, then apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nH_n}\sim1+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$$

Comment: You can [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1135536/147873) a more general result: if a series of positive terms $\sum a_n$ diverges then so does $\sum \frac{a_n}{ a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n}$. This is the special case where $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}
= \ln(n) + O(1)
$,
$\dfrac1{n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}}
=\dfrac1{n(\ln(n)+O(1))}
$
the sum of which diverges by,
for example,
condensation.

Comment: Marty, the last expression is missing a sum.

Comment: Note I wrote "the sum of which".

Comment: Yes, you certainly did.  I'm an idiot. (+1)

Comment: But I upvoted you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to work up some kind of drawing. As in a comment, the most elementary aspects of proof of the Integral Test give this: writing 
$$ H_n = 1 + \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{3} + \cdots + \frac {1}{n}, $$
we get the very ordinary
$$ H_n > \log ( n+1) $$ and
$$ H_n < 1 + \log n. $$
Here the logarithm is base $e \approx 2.71828.$

I drew in color, but my scanner does poorly with graph paper in color
[image]

Comment: (+1)  This is one of the easier ways forward and fit for purpose here.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

As the general term is decreasing, we can apply Cauchy's condensation criterion.
The convergence of the given series (or rather of $\sum \frac 1{n\ln n}$) is thus equivalent to that of 
$$\sum 2^k\cdot \frac1{2^k\ln 2^k} =\sum\frac1{k\ln 2}$$
so divergent.