# $\sum \frac{x_n}{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}$ convergent implies $\sum x_n$ convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I show that if $\displaystyle \sum \frac{x_n}{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}$ converges then $\displaystyle \sum x_n$ converges.

I was able to prove it the other way around, but I'm stuck for this one.

Comment: Are $x_{n}$'s all positive?

Comment: If $x_n>0$ then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808964/divergence-of-sum-limits-k-1n-fraca-ns-n-where-s-n-sum-limits-k

Comment: Yes, I believe all $x_n$'s are positive.